# Generating a random number in java based on user inputs for max and min

Tags: java

I having a little trouble trying to genertae a radom set of numbers with what the user defines as max and min, I am new to programming and feel a little lost with my code

```
int upperRange;
int lowerRange;
Random random = new Random(int)(Math.random()*(upperRange - (lowerRange-1)))+lowerRange;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


{

System.out.println("Enter upper limit number ");
upperRange = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter lower limit number");
lowerRange = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: why is there that curly bracket thing? `{`, show us whole `void` (function)

Answer (score 4):

Where r is an instance of class Random, and x and y are positive integers,

```
r.nextInt(y - x) + x
```

should do what you want.  It will give you an integer in the range x (inclusive) to y (exclusive).

Comment: Yes, it will ask the user to define the max/min range for a number guessing game

Comment: Good to know, sounds like you need integers only.  Just FYI the answer above assumes x and y are positive and x <= y.  Also, I should mention if the maximum bound is a legal guess, you'll need r.nextInt(y - x + 1), but do be careful of the case in which y is Integer.MAX_VALUE and x is 0.

Comment: Import java.util.Random, declare r as Random r = new Random(), and make sure x and y are declared as ints.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class TestRandomBounds {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int upperBound = 100;
        int lowerBound = 50;

        Random random = new Random();
        System.out.println(lowerBound + random.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound));

     }
}
```

Once the random bounds are defined you just need to generate a random number that will reside inside those bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be written like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandGuess
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        int upperRange;
        int lowerRange;
        Random random;
        int randomFromUserLimits;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter upper limit number: ");
        upperRange = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter lower limit number: ");
        lowerRange = keyboard.nextInt();
        random = new Random();
        randomFromUserLimits = random.nextInt(upperRange-lowerRange) + lowerRange;
        System.out.println("A random number between " + lowerRange + " and " + upperRange + " = " + randomFromUserLimits);
    }

}
```